# On the renormalization condition of the QED vertex function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, correlation-functions, scattering-cross-section

In any renormalizable theory, we exploit the so-called renormalization conditions to determine the finite part of the counter-term couplings (namely $Z_1, Z_2$, etc in QED). In the on-shell scheme, we start by requiring the pole of the full photon and fermion propagators to be the physical mass of the respective photon and fermion. This is the physical motivation behind choosing the renormalization conditions for the propagators at the loop level.

For the case of the vertex function in the on-shell renormalization scheme, we, once again, require both the incoming and outgoing fermion, as well as the photon that is produced during the interaction, to be on-shell. I know that this is the definition of the on-shell renormalization scheme and hence that is why we impose all of the interacting particles to be on shell.

**However**, we are taught that the values for the corrected vertex function at some energy scale $\Lambda_1$ are identified with the values of the vertex function at the same energy scale from experimental observations. Then, once we have the value of the vertex function from experiment, we have enough information to deduce the form of the corrected vertex function at any given energy scale $\Lambda$. The experiment that will give us the vertex function for the energy scale $\Lambda_1$ involves measuring the differential cross section of an interaction that has taken place at that energy scale. This is the story for justifying renormalization conditions for the vertex function.

**Paradox:** Applying the reasoning above, we should fix the QED loop-corrected vertex by experimental data regarding cross sections of a $e^-\rightarrow e^-\gamma$ interaction (in which all the particles are on-shell). This interaction, however, in QED, is prohibited by momentum conservation. **How do we get around that?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually,  the on-shell scheme does not require the particles to be on shell for the vertex function. They are only on shell for the other prescriptions (self energies and pole residue).

Take for example Peskin and Schroeder's *An Introduction to quantum Field Theory*. There it is only required that $q=0$ (the 4-momentum of the photon). Intuitively, this is to be interpreted as the low energy limit. In practice, you can get it by looking at the weak scattering of the electron from an ambient EM field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am reading Srednicki's book on QFT, specifically the Chapter on "The Vertex Function in Spinor Electrodynamics". He says that he chooses the renormalization condition such that both fermions and the photon are on-shell.

Comment: I don't have the book myself. The claim you quoted is false taken at face value, basic kinematics is hard to argue with, but perhaps in the context it could have a slightly different salvageable meaning. A possible loophole is to say that $q=0$ is in the closure of the on shell prescription (zero energy limit of the photon), so it could also counts. In any case, there is no deep physical meaning, it is merely conventional and should be adapted depending on your needs.

Comment: Truth be told, the author says that $p'^2=p^2=-m^2,\ (p'-p)^2=0$ and conservation of momentum forces $p'=p$, but I can not see the physical significance of evaluating the vertex function under those circumstances (and there should be some motivation, right? Otherwise how does this story with the measurable cross section add up?). The book is readily available online btw